# trackBy in ngfor not worker Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with mat-slide-toggle to update the state of a field in my database (Firestore). The problem is that I see that it has a strange behavior in the other elements when pressing it (a flicker).

I've been reading that using trackBy prevents these types of behavior. I used it but the error stays.

[image]

lista-items.component.html

```
<app-card-item-admin *ngFor="let item of group.items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByPublicado" [idNegocio]="idNegocio" [item]="item"></app-card-item-admin>
```

lista-items.components.ts

```
actualizarPublicado(idItem, publicado) { this.afs.collection('negocios').doc(this.idNegocio).collection('items').doc(idItem).update({publicado});
  }    

trackByPublicado(item) {
      return item.publicado;
    }
```

card-item-admin.component.html

```
<div class="position-relative bg-white rounded-3 border">

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

    <div class="me-2">
      <img class="imageItemAdmin rounded-start" [src]="item.image">
    </div>

    <div class="w-100">
      <p class="nombreItem mb-0 mt-1 lh-1">{{item.nombre}}</p>
      <p class="descripcionItem mb-0">{{item.descripcion | slice:0:32}}...</p>
      <span class="me-2" [ngClass]=" !item.precioDescuento ? 'text-decoration-line-through small text-muted' : 'precioItem' " *ngIf="item.precioDescuento">S/. {{item.precioDescuento}}</span>
      <span [ngClass]=" item.precioDescuento ? 'text-decoration-line-through small text-muted' : 'precioItem' " >S/. {{item.precio}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="pe-2 pt-2">
      <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" #toggle [ngModel]="item.publicado" (ngModelChange)="actualizarPublicado(item.id, $event)">
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the code for `actualizarPublicado` ?

Comment: @SlawaEremin I have updated the code please look again. Basically update a field from `publicado` to true or false, the database is in Firebase Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the reason is the way you use ngModel and ngModelChange, try to switch to just using `checked` property and `change` event for `mat-slide-toggle` like below

```
actualizarPublicado(idItem, change: MatSlideToggleChange) { 
 this.afs.collection('negocios')
   .doc(this.idNegocio)
   .collection('items')
   .doc(idItem)
   .update({
      publicado: change.checked
   });
}  


<mat-slide-toggle
  #toggle
  color="primary"
  [checked]="item.publicado"
  (change)="actualizarPublicado(item.id, $event)">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks a lot. So what is the approach in using ngModel and/or checked?